# corrupted file, on flash drive, renamed itself "&", and won't open on hard drive either

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, openoffice, file-recovery

I have a document on flashdrive that suddenly changed to working marvelously to not opening at all.  Somehow the file name changed to "&".  when I open the file I get this:  "  & refers to a location that is unavailable.  It could be saved to a harddrive on this computer or network."

I have checked everywhere I can think of -- trash, temp, %temp%, I have used a recovery program on computer and flashdrive  and anything that I think could possibly be the file opens up to an ASCII, which I can't open.  I have tried saving as a zip file and reopening.  I have changed document type from .odf to .txt or .rtf.  Nothing.  I can't find the document or open it.

I am working on a junk computer.  Old.  Windows 7.  Open Office program.  Yes, I have tried opening it on another computer, including an IMAC and have attempted to open in Microsoft Word and Office.  Nothing

Sadly, this document means everything to my chronically ill teenager.  She has been crazy sick and stuck at home for a decade.  You could say this is her life's work.      Please keep in mind, when responding to this that I am not tech savvy.  I'm just a stubborn Mom who is willing to research for answers and attempt to apply them, in order to give my child some hope again in life. She truly lived each day to write and survived each day because of her writing.

Comment: What happens if you try opening it from the command prompt? (start->cmd, then use cd to navigate to the drive, and type the following command `ren "&.txt" file.txt` then open it normally? & is a reserved character in windows.

Comment: If you can't open it under windows, download some linux version, e.g. linux mint, burn it to DVD or copy it to a usb stick and boot from that. Try to copy the file to hard disk first before opening it. Don't experiment with the original file if you don't have a backup copy.

Comment: Get a hex editor, e.g. HxD and try to open the file with that. HxD can open any kind of file and display all bytes the file consists of. You can then post lets say the first 100 bytes or so in this forum and we can tell you if  it looks like an undamaged word file (assuming it is a word file).

Comment: THANKS for all the great suggestions!  I'll work on them today.

Comment: Unfortunately, regarding suggestion from SpiderPig to créate a backup copy.  Once it renamed itself to "&" - - - it won't allow me to copy it.  If you have some computer wiz suggestion as to how to accomplish that - I'm listening.  : )

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't see your comment earlier. If you can't copy it under Windows, try Linux instead. Ubuntu and Linux Mint are some of the most user friendly Linux versions.

If that doesn't work you can always copy the "raw" data with dd. There is a Windows version of dd at http://www.chrysocome.net/dd

The file you need is this one http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.zip

It's a command line tool. That means you have to start a command prompt and run it from there. You have to start the command prompt as an administrator. But first you insert the USB stick. Then you use the cd command to get to the folder where you unzipped dd. Then you type in `dd --list` to get a list of all devices you can read from.
One of the entries towards the end of the list should be the USB stick. It will say something like this:

```
\\?\Device\Harddisk2\Partition0
  link to \\?\Device\Harddisk2\DR2
  Removable media other than floppy. Block size = 512
  size is 2021654528 bytes
```

Now you can copy the stick with this command:

`dd if=\\?\Device\Harddisk2\Partition0 of=c:\usb.img bs=1M --size --progress`
Afterwards you can use the HxD hex editor to open the file (c:\usb.img) and search for the document.

Be careful to choose the correct device and type in the command correctly. dd can be dangerous and destroy all your data if used incorrectly.